# Library of ancient Linear A and Linear B text images?

Tags: images, language

Is there an open-data library of text\language images for ancient [Linear A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_A) and [Linear B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_B) languages?